# How to get desired machine column datas?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, graph

I have a code that shows a graph of temperature and water of machines, Here is my code

```
 public List<Sinif1> Urunlistesi()
    {
        List<Sinif1> snf = new List<Sinif1>();
        using (var w = new HMIEntities1())
        {
            snf = w.Webapisqls.Select(x => new Sinif1
            {
                urunad = x.Su.Value, // water
                sıcaklık= x.Sıcaklık.Value // temperature
            }).ToList();
        }
        return snf;
    }
```

And here is my view code a bit ;

```
 $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
                            //   water      temp
            dataArray.push([obj.urunad, obj.sıcaklık]);

        });

        data.addRows(dataArray);
```

Where Sıcaklık = temperature and Su = Water but when I showed my graphs I wanna show it for each machine, I have an SQL database like this
[Where makine_durum means that machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKADb.png)

For example, I want to select the 192.168.0.8 machine and I want to get all the data of this machine.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow what you're asking here. Where does machine come into this?

Comment: You can see in sql database photo machine name is 192.168.0.8, but it is not important I just want to select desired values instead of all database values how can I use query in type of situation

Comment: Is `w` a `DbContext` and `w.Webapisqls` your table?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: Then do you not just want a `.Where( )` in your query? P.S. you should tell people if you're using Entity Framework / LINQ-to-SQL. It's a common way of working, but it's far from the only way. At my workplace we use MongoDB for our ASP.NET web API. When you use strange variable names like `w` rather than `db` as most people do, it becomes harder to follow what you're doing.